# How do I render a SwiftUI View that is not at the root hierarchy as a UIImage?

Tags: uikit, swiftui

Suppose I have a simple SwiftUI View that is not the ContentView such as this:

```
struct Test: View {        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Test 1")
            Text("Test 2")
        }
    }
}
```

How can I render this view as a UIImage?

I've looked into solutions such as :

```
extension UIView {
    func asImage() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems that solutions like that only work on UIView, not a SwiftUI View.

Comment: https://ericasadun.com/2019/06/20/swiftui-render-your-mojave-swiftui-views-on-the-fly/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is the approach that works for me, as I needed to get image exactly sized as it is when placed alongside others. Hope it would be helpful for some else.

Demo: above divider is SwiftUI rendered, below is image (in border to show size)

#### Update: re-tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[Test module in project is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestBackgroundRendering.swift)

[image]

```
extension View {
    func asImage() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)

        // locate far out of screen
        controller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat(Int.max), width: 1, height: 1)

        let size = controller.sizeThatFits(in: UIScreen.main.bounds.size)
        controller.view.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        controller.view.sizeToFit()
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(controller.view)

        let image = controller.view.asImage()
        controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
        return image
    }
}
```

```
extension UIView {
    func asImage() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
// [!!] Uncomment to clip resulting image
//             rendererContext.cgContext.addPath(
//                UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 20).cgPath)
//            rendererContext.cgContext.clip()

// As commented by @MaxIsom below in some cases might be needed
// to make this asynchronously, so uncomment below DispatchQueue
// if you'd same met crash
//            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
//            }
        }
    }
}


// TESTING
struct TestableView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Test 1")
            Text("Test 2")
        }
    }
}

struct TestBackgroundRendering: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TestableView()
            Divider()
            Image(uiImage: render())
                .border(Color.black)
        }
    }
    
    private func render() -> UIImage {
        TestableView().asImage()
    }
}
```

Comment: It works! Now if I needed specifically to use a UIImage type inside my view instead of Image would that be possible? Since in the code here we have `Image(uiImage: render())`, is there an equivalent UIImage expression with the render? And can we even use UIImage in a SwiftUI View?

Comment: `render()` returns UIImage and `Image(uiImage:)` is exactly usage of UIImage in SwiftUI.

Comment: Needed a UIImage type variable for a 3rd party SDK integration, so I've just used `.asImage().pngData()` to convert the resulting UIImage from `render()` to data so that I can use `UIImage(data: ___ )`. Not sure if this is best practice but works fine!

Small follow-up: is there any possible way to add a cornerRadius to the CGRect that is used to capture the View? So that the resulting image of the View has rounded corners and is not a perfect rectangle?

Comment: Added in comment the way how to clip rendering image

Comment: @Asperi Apparently it does not work if `TestableView` contains dynamic data which is passed down to it using `@Binding`. Getting `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` in `layer.render` line of UIView extension.

Comment: @Asperi would it be possible to render a View as an Image the way you've implemented it, on tap of a Button inside that View?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with dynamic data. @AnaghSharma did you find a way to solve it?

Comment: I was able to prevent it from crashing by wrapping `self.layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)` with `DispatchQueue.main.async {}`

Comment: This doesn't work if the view contains a map view in it.

Comment: This crashes for me, even with the DispatchQueue.main.async

Comment: How might you go about using this in an extension? (Messages extension, I'm using SwiftUI rather than UIKit). Xcode complains that "UIApplication.shared" is "unavailable in application extensions for iOS: Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead. ". In a SwiftUI app, this works perfectly. (Thank you for that!)

Comment: Does this only works if the (parent) view is rendered on screen? When I try to use this off screen all I get is an empty image.

Comment: I get empty image with  DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in layer.render }, but correct image without

Comment: Doesnt Work in Xcode 12.4. no particular error. just would not display in preview.

Comment: @Asperi, This solution works perfect, until I use it for single Views, but if I use this solution inside of Foreach, it crashes with error "AttributeGraph precondition failure: setting value during update: 2072". What could be the solution?

Comment: @Asperi this is not working when You try to convert swiftUI View inside ViewController of storyboard

Answer (score 3):

Solution of Asperi works, but if you need image without white background you have to add this line:

```
controller.view.backgroundColor = .clear
```

And your View extension will be:

```
extension View {
    func asImage() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        
        // locate far out of screen
        controller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat(Int.max), width: 1, height: 1)
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(controller.view)
        
        let size = controller.sizeThatFits(in: UIScreen.main.bounds.size)
        controller.view.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        controller.view.sizeToFit()
        controller.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        let image = controller.view.asImage()
        controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
        return image
    }
}
```

Comment: If you add modifier as .backgroundColor()  to TestableView() will present that color.

Comment: this solution is not working as I am trying to convert swiftUI in storyboard ViewController. It is showing simply white box nothing else