# Converting SwiftUI View Into Image

Tags: swift, function, swiftui

I have a Snapshot function that converts my SwiftUI view into an image but it seems to cut off a large proportion of the contents in my View.

How can I adjust the Snapshot function so that it captures all of the contents of my VStack and doesn't cut anything off?

Expected result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1qsc.png

Actual result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGmky.png

```
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    
    func theNewOfficialSnapshot() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view
        
        let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)
        
        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
    
}


struct SnapshotView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            
            let image = self.theNewOfficialSnapshot()
            print(image)
            
        }, label:{
            
            VStack{
            Text("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.")
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .background(Color.white)
                .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous))
                .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)).opacity(0.3), radius: 10, x: 0, y:10)
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: 300)
            
            }
        })
        
    }
}

struct SnapshotView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SnapshotView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59333377/12299030?

Comment: Yesss thank you so much, that solution is much cleaner 

Answer (score 0):

Add `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` to your Text.