# White strip on iPad when rendering a view to an image

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to render a black rectangle to an image and save it to the photo library. But every time I render it on my iPad, the picture has a white strip on the top, that doesn’t happen if I do this on the iPhone.
I am using Swift Playgrounds 4, so maybe that’s the reason. It’s a bit strange, since both Views the small and the bigger one are both „iPads“.
Thank you for your help!
That’s my code so far:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Snapshot") { 
                // Save Screenshot
                let image = snapshotView.snapshot()
                
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
            }
        }
    }
    var snapshotView: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view
        
        let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)
        
        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

[Image of the Rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p46t.jpg)

Comment: This should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/59333377/12299030 - tested on iPad as well - works fine. Xcode 13.4 / iPadOS 15.5

Comment: But is there a way to save the image as an UIImage to photo libary?

Comment: call-back, side-effect, modifier, ... anything

Comment: Could you please explain it in more detail ?

Comment: I have tried it now this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59333377/12299030.
But the white strip is now on the bottom. 
It only happens when I tap on the run button, but everything works fine in the preview!